# How do I find the max from a list of integers

Tags: java

```
int playerOne = 4;
int playerTwo = 8;
int playerThree = 2;
int playerFour = 8;

public static int max(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4) {
    if(p1 > p2 && p1 > p3 && p1 > p4){
        return p1;
    } else if (p2 > p1 && p2 > p3 && p2 > p4) {
        return p2;
    } else if ...


}
```

I am wondering is the is a better way to recreate the function above with less repetitiveness.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a better question for code review.

Comment: Oh sorry where do I need to move it to or do I just change the tag.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get Hotspot to generate SIMD instructions for the generalized case.

Comment: I do not agree this is a code review, it's really a code question. It's not correctly asked, but I definitely believe it has its place here on SO. Basically, it's a question on how to find the max between n values, with a not so good example.

Comment: _"So for example instead of just the highest score returned but the name of the varible which is belongs to."_ What if the variables have no names? What if I call `max(4, 8, 15, 16)`?

Comment: Sorry Kevin that was irrelevant for now and poorly worded I removed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static int max(int[] integers) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int e : integers) max = Math.max(max, e);
    return max;
}
```

Now for the implementation that could also return information about variable name:

```
//Returns the array index of the maximum integer
public static int max(int[] integers) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int retVal = -1;
    if (integers == null) return retVal;  //needs to handle this case too
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, integers[i]);
        if (integers[i] == max) retVal = i;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

These implementations also have the advantage of being able to handle arrays of any size, not just 4.

Comment: @La-comadreja You should initialize `max` with one of the values from `integers` instead of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. `Integer.MIN_VALUE` doesn't even exists in your input array so if your input array is empty, it will return `Integer.MIN_VALUE` which is wrong.

Comment: @Yatendra, what about if integers is empty or is null?  2nd implementation changed to handle null.  The reason to print Integer.MIN_VALUE (or retVal == -1) is that it becomes a clear indication that the array has no values.

Comment: @Yatendra, the 2nd implementation returns an index (see the comment above the method) and indices can't be negative in Java.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 this would be:

```
private int max(int... ints) {
    if (ints.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return Arrays.stream(ints).max().getAsInt();
}
```

Explanation in steps:

1. Ensure that `ints.length > 0`.
2. Create an `IntStream`.
3. Get maximum value with `max()` on the `IntStream`.
4. Get the `int` and return it, out of the `OptionalInt` that `max()` returns.

I hope it helps for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int max(int[] integers) {
    int max = integers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < integers.length; i++)
        max = Math.max(max, integers[i]);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: @La-comadreja has a better solution, iterators is so much more XXIst century :-)

Comment: Except for the risk of an empty array, this makes sense

Comment: @zmo There is a reason behind not using iterators. I am intializing the `max` value with first integer in the array. Which should ideally be the case instead of initializing the `max` with some value which doesn't even exists in your input array.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the wrapper class `Integer`, you could do:

```
public static int max(Integer... values){
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(values));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just for the fun of it, I'm giving a recursive way, it's no way better than the other options, but it's fun ;-)

```
public static int get_max(int[] integers) {
    switch (integers.length) {
        case 0:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        case 1:
            return integers[0];
        case 2:
            return Math.max(integers[0],integers[1]);
        default:
            return Math.max(integers[0], get_max(Arrays.copyOfRange(integers, 1, integers.length-1));
    }
}
```

afaict it should be working, but it's not memory efficient at all because it's copying the array (less one value) at each recursion, and eats memory for each function call for each recursion.

`<3`